# Warning MSB3274 when publishing in Visual Studio 2017 after Upgrade from .NET 4.5.2 to 4.6.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I have been encountering several of these warnings after upgrading from .NET 4.5.2 to 4.6.1

> 3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5):
>   Warning MSB3274: The primary reference
>   "[...]AbcManagement.Commons.dll" could not be resolved because it was
>   built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" framework. This is a
>   higher version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2".

I have checked all referenced projects. All of them target Framework 4.6.1 now. The Solutions Builds without Errors or Warnings and it also runs localy. Only when I try to publish the solution using: right click on project -> publish, it starts the publish and exists with an error, which is related to this warning.

I have read on similar threads, to make sure to have installed the correct Framework on the local machine. This also led to no satisfying result.

What am I missing?

Comment: clean obj/bin folders and rebuild whole solution

Comment: unfortunately did not fix my problem. Thank you for pointing out this approach though.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a new project, add my .cs files into the new Project and reinstall all NuGet Packages. This finally solved the problem.

After setting up the new project, I compared the configuration files but couldn't find differences in the configurations which would affect this issue. Unfortunately, therefore I can't point out the exact change made to make the publish work in a completely new project.